# How to retrieve JSON with Php and utilize with jQuery on a webpage?

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to retrieve data from a mysql table. My php script is as follows:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$jsonData = json_encode($data);
echo($jsonData);
```

It is giving me this result when the php url is called from browser:

```
[{"id":"p1","image_data":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,largestring","image_status":"","image_returnedbit":""},{"id":"p2","image_data":"data:image\/jpeg;base64,largestring","image_status":"","image_returnedbit":""}]
```

(I have only two rows in the mysql table. The extra two columns in the array aren't processed atm)
And I'm having a hard time trying to utilize that data. I have this html file (consistingg some css, html too but not included):

```
    $(function () {
    $("#button-get").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://www.example.com/myphpfile.php",  
            dataType: "",              
            success: function(response){ 
                // alert(response);
                // alert(response["id"]);
                console.log(response[0]);
                // $(".image-gallery").append(`<div class="image-single"><img src=${}></div>`);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It seems like an array is being echoed, but logging `response(0)` gives `[` and logging `response(1)` gives `{`. Please assist me if someone can :) would really appreciate.
Any help is appreciated.
Previously, I tried `echo($data)` on the php script, but it only showed a word `Array` on the browser and/on console log. I believe `echo($jsonData)` is sending a string which I'd have to play with to get values (splitting and removing certain characters). How can I achieve retrieving data that I can feasibly use on my html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the ajax is treating the response as string not as json so you have two options either use `JSON.parse(response)` to convert the json string to json object or you need to set `dataType` to `json`

Comment: Thank you so very much brother! Setting `datatype` to `json` worked perfectly :). Many thanks.